# Email notifications go straight into spam email folder

Tags: cognito-forms, spam-prevention, notifications

After setting up a Cognito form for an order process for our clients I realized that all email notifications are being sent straight to our junk folders. Whitelisting the following sender adresses didn't change the slightest thing:

no-reply@cognitoforms.com
@cognitoforms.com
@mandrillapp.com

How can I prevent this?

Comment: I'm a developer with Cognito Forms. Can you submit a support request (https://www.cognitoforms.com/supportrequest/)? We could then work with you to help correct the email issue your encountering.

Comment: No reply on my email?!